# R accurate labels for stacked bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

to begin here's some reprex data:

```
df.test <- data.frame(
       stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                                    
                                       GENDER = c("Male",
                                                  "Male","Male","Male",
                                                  "Male","Male","Female","Male",
                                                  "Male","Male","Male",
                                                  "Female","Female","Female","Male",
                                                  "Male","Male","Female",
                                                  "Male","Male","Male","Male",
                                                  "Male","Male","Male",
                                                  "Female","Female","Male","Female",
                                                  "Female"),
                                         ETHN = c("White",
                                                  "Hispanic","Hispanic",
                                                  "Black/African American",
                                                  "Black/African American",
                                                  "Black/African American",
                                                  "Declined to Answer","Hispanic","Hispanic",
                                                  "Hispanic",
                                                  "Hawaiian/Pacific Islander","Hispanic",
                                                  "Hispanic","Hispanic","White",
                                                  "White","White","Asian","Asian",
                                                  "Hispanic","Hispanic",
                                                  "Hispanic","Hispanic","Hispanic",
                                                  "Hispanic","White","White",
                                                  "White","Hispanic",
                                                  "Hispanic"),
                                  
                                
                                     
                                    GRDE_CODE = c("F",
                                                  "A-","B+","F","CRD","C",
                                                  "CRD","C+","B+","B+","B",
                                                  "B+","NCR","NCR","CRD","C-",
                                                  "C","A-","CRD","D","C+",
                                                  "B","B+","IP","INC","A",
                                                  "A","A","F","A"),
                                
                         
                                   Course.lvl = as.factor(c("200-level",
                                                            "300-level","300-level",
                                                            "200-level",
                                                            "300-level","200-level",
                                                            "100-level",
                                                            "300-level","300-level",
                                                            "400-level",
                                                            "300-level","200-level",
                                                            "200-level",
                                                            "200-level","100-level",
                                                            "200-level",
                                                            "300-level","200-level",
                                                            "200-level",
                                                            "100-level","300-level",
                                                            "300-level","300-level",
                                                            "400-level",
                                                            "300-level","300-level",
                                                            "300-level",
                                                            "200-level","100-level",
                                                            "300-level"))
                      )
```

What I want to do is created a stacked bar chart with labels of the respective percentages using the data above. My code works well, it visualizes everything, but my problem is that I can't seem to get accurate labels for my data.

```
df.test %>%
  filter(!(GRDE_CODE %in% c("IP", "INC", "NG"))) %>%
  filter(Course.lvl %in% c("200-level", "100-level"
  )) %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = GRDE_CODE, fill = GENDER) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  # geom_text(aes(label = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(Female = "#F99A46", 
                               Male = "#0BB021", `Not Reported` = "#3404DD")) +
  labs(x = "Grade Code", y = "% of Grade", title = "Math - 100/200") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic() +
  facet_grid(vars(), vars(Course.lvl))
```

I attempted to use

```
geom_text(aes(label = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image: reprex stacked bar w/o data labels]
(example of graph generated)

but I get an error each time. Is there a way to label the bars with the relative percentages (and possibly counts of each) without having to resort to tons of mutate functions? If not, what's the best way to keep track so that my data doesn't get mislabeled?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: As a start you'd need `stat = "count"` in your `geom_text()`, although this won't calculate the percentages by group for you. I think you'll be interested in `stat_prop()` from **GGally** as shown [here](https://ggobi.github.io/ggally/articles/ggally_stats.html#stat-prop-) to do this task. Calculating the proportions of interest doesn't seem particularly onerous to me, but to each their own. See [this **ggplot2** GitHub thread](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3369) with **dplyr** example code and other discussion.

Comment: were you able to produce the graph desired via your examples?

Comment: Maybe? I'm not 100% positive what you want the labels to be, but I could make one with the observed counts for each gender per bar with standard **ggplot2** `stat = "count"` and `label = after_stat(count)` and another with the proportion of each "Gender" labeled within each bar by using the **GGally** example with `stat = "prop"` plus `by = factor(GRDE_CODE)` added to `aes()`.

Comment: curious, do you know if I can also include counts of these as well next to their percentage? It might be a tad crowded but it could be useful from time to time

Comment: Based on `?GGally::state_prop`, it looks like `count` is one of the "Computed variables". That means you could refer to both `count` and `prop` in the labels if using `after_stat()`. See the last example in that documentation for use of `after_stat()` with `prop`. You could maybe use `paste()` in there somehow to get both.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(GGally, quietly = TRUE)

df.test %>%
  filter(!(GRDE_CODE %in% c("IP", "INC", "NG"))) %>%
  filter(Course.lvl %in% c("200-level", "100-level"
  )) %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = GRDE_CODE, fill = GENDER, by=as.factor(GRDE_CODE)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  geom_text(stat = "prop", position = position_fill(.5))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(Female = "#F99A46", 
                               Male = "#0BB021", `Not Reported` = "#3404DD")) +
  labs(x = "Grade Code", y = "% of Grade", title = "Math - 100/200") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic() +
  facet_grid(vars(), vars(Course.lvl))
```

The above code gave me my desired output. Thanks to [aosmith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2461552/aosmith) for the help